# CakePhp 2.6.3 Auth component not working. Accepting any userID/password combination

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I have been trying to get cakephp 2.6.3 auth component for my site to work for a week now.

The problem am facing is that when ever I enter any bogus user ID/password combination, the login function returns true. i have read all is there to read and watched tutorials but I can't seem to get this to work.

I am new to using Cake, your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Below is my appController.

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components = array(
'DebugKit.Toolbar', 
'Session',
'Auth' => array(
    'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
    'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
    'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),

    'Authenticate' => array(
        'Form' => array(
            'fields' => array('username' => 'student_id', 'password' => 'password')
         )
    )

    )
);


public function isAuthorized($user){
return true;
}

public function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Auth->allow('login');




    }

}
```

UsersController:

```
public function login(){

        if($this->request->is('post')){
            if($this->Auth->login()){

                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());   
            }

            else{

               $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid User ID or password');
            }
        }
}
```

User's model:

```
class User extends AppModel{
public $name = 'User';

public $validate = array(
'student_id' => array(
'Please enter your User ID' => array(
'rule' => 'notEmpty',
'message' => 'Please enter your User ID.'
)
),
    'first_name' => array(
    'Enter First Name' => array(
    'rule' => 'notEmpty',
    'Message' => 'Please enter first name.')),

    'last_name' => array(
    'Enter Last Name' => array(
    'rule' => 'notEmpty',
    'Message' => 'Please enter last name.')),

    'email' => array(
    'Valid email' => array(
    'rule' => array ('email'),
    'Message' => 'Please enter a valid email.')),

    'password' => array(
    'Not empty' => array(
    'rule' => 'notEmpty',
    'Message' => 'Please enter your password.'),

    'Match passwords' => array(
    'rule' => 'matchPasswords',
    'Message' => 'Your passwords donot match')),

    'password_confirmation' => array(
    'Not empty' => array(
    'rule' => 'notEmpty',
    'Message' => 'Please confirm your password.'))



);

public function matchPasswords($data){

if($data['password'] == $this->data['User']['password_confirmation']){
return true;
}
$this->invalidate('password_confirmation', 'Your passwords do not match');
    return false;
}


public function beforeSave($options = array()){
if(isset($this->data['User']['password'])){
$this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
}
return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good answer here :
[Cake PHP 2.4.x. AuthComponent login() always return true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857977/cake-php-2-4-x-authcomponent-login-always-return-true);

Also read this :
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in

Comment: Thanks Mouloud, your links really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `$this->Auth->allow('login');` from your `beforeFilter()` method.